# Как пишется много раз "да"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Да()да()да()да,вы правы.
Нет()нет()нет()нет,вы не правы.

Дефис или запятая?

Answer (score 2):

**1) Основной формой является запятая** (интонация перечисления):

Точно, точно… **Да, да, да**… Правильно… [Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)]

Артист вытянул вперёд руку, на пальцах которой сверкали камни, как бы заграждая уста буфетчику, и заговорил с большим жаром: ― **Нет, нет, нет**! Ни слова больше! [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

2) **Дефис встречается крайне редко** (произношение без паузы):

― **Да-да-да**, ― трижды сказал Штрум, ― что же ещё? [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 3 (1960)]

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от контекста и подразумеваемой интонации, но как правило, дефис.

Answer (score 1):

> Как пишется много раз “да”?.. Дефис или запятая?

Выбор знака зависит от того, какую интонацию пишущий хочет отобразить на письме.

**Дефис**  —  быстрое произнесение. Такое использование дефиса при повторении слова предусмотрено правилами [**ПАС (см. §118)**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/).

**Запятая**   —  более размеренное произнесение.

.

Ср. примеры:

***Да-да-да-да-да,*** вы правы (он [Б. Пастернак] **любил повторять** “да”)
(Н. Любимов "Неувядаемый цвет").

***— Да, да, да,*** вы говорили... — у него возвышенная чувствительность, — **пролепетал** Захария 
(Н. С. Лесков "Соборяне").