# Ставятся ли дефисы, если слово повторяется три раза подряд?

Tags: орфография

Ставятся ли дефисы, если одно слово повторяется три раза (в разговорной речи)? Например: "Нет-нет-нет".
Можно ли вообще где-либо ставить два дефиса подряд между словами?

Comment: См. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427135/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: Здесь у Вас, кстати, три слова, а дефиса-то только два.) Если только Вы не отдельно спрашиваете о трёх.

Comment: В русском обычно говорят в два слова: "Нет-нет!" - это случаем не перевод английского No, no, no? Есть ещё русский отказ: "Нет, нет и нет!"

Answer (score 2):

Вы спрашиваете о тире, а в вопросе - дефисы, однако...

Тире можно - АВТОРУ! - ставить между словами три и более: такова его воля:

> Далеко — в ночи — по асфальту — трость,
>
> Двери настежь — в ночь — под ударом ветра…

См.: **[Дефисное написание междометий и звукоподражательных слов](https://slovar.wikireading.ru/3206020)**

> Сложные междометия и звукоподражательные слова пишутся через дефис,
> например: ей-же-ей, о-го-го-го, ой-ой-ой, ха-ха-ха, динь-динь-динь,
> кис-кис, мяу-мяу.

Как Вы догадались, наверное, слова наподобие ой-ой-ой, ха-ха-ха, динь-динь-динь, можно длить до бесконечности.

***Ой-ё-ё-ё-ёшеньки!***

Comment: Спасибо, действительно имела ввиду дефисы, а не тире. Исправила

Answer (score 0):

Вторая часть вашего вопроса:
**Можно ли вообще где-либо ставить два дефиса подряд между словами?**

Может ли быть два дефиса в слове?
Да, может. Непривычно, необычно, но по правилам. Вот какое указание дает Лопатин:
§ 152. Недопустимо слитное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть слова содержит дефис. Слитное написание должно заменяться дефисным, в результате чего возникают написания с двумя дефисами.
Например, следует писать: *полу-конференц-зал, полу-социал-демократы, ультра-ура-патриот, радио-мюзик-холл, теле-пресс-конференция, теле-ток-шоу, анти-социал-демократический, лже-тред-юнионистский, псевдо-историко-революционный.*

[Конечно, это совсем иной случай, чем аудиовидеоаппаратура или мультимедиатехнологии: в последних словах нет частей, которые следует писать через дефис, а значит, корректно слитное написание. Хоть и неудобоваримо.]

С двумя дефисами пишутся:
точь-в-точь, по-честному-то;
иван-да-марья, мать-и-мачеха;
Семенов-Тян-Шанский, Овчина-Оболенский-Телепнев;
серо-буро-малиновый (и похожие);
русско-немецко-французский [разговорник, словарь] (и другие);
Комсомольск-на-Амуре, Ростов-на-Дону, Франкфурт-на-Майне;
экс-премьер-министр, вице-премьер-министр (слова с иноязычными приставками);
ку-клукс-клан, тет-а-тет, рок-н-ролл, корнет-а-пистон, па-де-труа;
бом-брам-стеньга, фор-бом-брам-рей (морские термины);
юго-юго-запад, северо-северо-восток...

P.S. Не следует путать дефис и тире. Дефис — орфографический знак, тире — пунктуационный.